# Return the next whole number

Tags: c#, .net

I want to pass a number and have the next whole number returned,

I've tried `Math.Ceiling(3)` , but it returns 3.

Desired output :

```
double val = 9.1 => 10
double val = 3 => 4
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just add `1` to each number, then grab the floor?  So `Math.Floor(input + 1)`

Comment: another way you could do this is just get the value of int
(val + 1), which will cut off all of the decimals, if you wanted it to round to the next whole number, you could use Math.round(val + 1)

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways I would suggest doing this:

Using `Math.Floor()`:

```
return Math.Floor(input + 1);
```

Using casting (to lose precision)

```
return (int)input + 1;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H5kYQr)

Comment: Or `Math.Ceiling`?  Nevermind, I see the requirement of OP to convert 3.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: he wants 4 if you pass 3 if you look at the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Using just the floor or ceiling wont give you the next whole number in every case.
For eg:- If you input negative numbers. Better way is to create a function that does that.

```
public class Test{ 

    public int NextWholeNumber(double n)
    {
        if(n < 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(n)+1);
    }

    // Main method 
    static public void Main() 
    { 
        Test o = new Test();
        Console.WriteLine(o.NextWholeNumber(1.254)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Because the problem statement says, return the next whole number(not integer) on input.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you refer to whole number it is positive integers only. But if you require negative integers as well then you can try this, the code will return 3.0 => 4, -1.0 => 0, -1.1 => -1

```
double doubleValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int wholeNumber = 0;
if ((doubleValue - Math.Floor(doubleValue) > 0))
{
    wholeNumber = int.Parse(Math.Ceiling(doubleValue).ToString());
}
else
{
    wholeNumber = int.Parse((doubleValue + 1).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why the Parse/ToString combination?

Comment: The variable wholenumber is an integer type so it requires double value to be parsed from double to int. We can also use 'wholeNumber = (int)Math.Ceiling(doubleValue);'  for the same. If I am missing something would love to know.

Comment: I expect the cast to be much faster than the ToString+Parse. And you are certain that there are no culture issues with the conversion to/from string. Plus the intent of the code is much clearer.